# jquery select option set value from json

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

i've code html like :

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "hanca/hanca_crud.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    id_hanca: id_hanca,
    type: "detail_hanca"
  }, //detail_hanca
  success: function(data) {

    var teks = "";
    $.each(data.detail, function(indeks, nilai) {
      //status hanca
      var tmp1 = nilai.status_detail_hanca;
      $("select.status_detail_hanca").val(tmp1);

      var no = nilai.no;
      var status_detail_hanca = "<select class='status_detail_hanca' name='status_detail_hanca[]' ><option value='0'>Proses</option><option value='1'>Return</option><option value='2'>Selesai</option></select>";
      teks += "<tr>" + no +
        "</td><td>" + status_detail_hanca +
        "</td></tr>";
    });
    $(".tbody_detail_hanca_checking").append(teks);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>No.</th>
      <th>Status Proses</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="tbody_detail_hanca_checking">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and this output json :

```html
{
 "detail": [{
  "status_detail_hanca": "2",
  "no": 1
 }, {
  "status_detail_hanca": "0",
  "no": 2
 }]
}
```

i use ajax to get data by json, i want create a `select option` and set the `value` data from json. but, its not work. how to fix it ?

***text dummy for allow code*** Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi vel fermentum massa, quis viverra lectus. Aliquam tristique feugiat volutpat. Donec elementum sapien vel enim facilisis sollicitudin. Integer pellentesque volutpat enim

Comment: where is the select element>?

Comment: `status_detail_hanca` dynamically added

Comment: this is create a element with jquery, like this : ` var status_detail_hanca = "<select class='status_detail_hanca' name='status_detail_hanca[]' ><option value='0'>Proses</option><option value='1'>Return</option><option value='2'>Selesai</option></select>";`

Comment: what value do you want to set from the json?

Comment: if json return `"status_detail_hanca": "2"` then `<option value='2'>Selesai</option>` is selected

Comment: please help guys, i had tried `var tmp1 = nilai.status_detail_hanca;
      $("select.status_detail_hanca").val(tmp1);` for selected `value` .but its not change in `select option`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select.status_detail_hanca").val(tmp1);
```

This will not work as you are trying to set the select option before you have written the same by - `$(".tbody_detail_hanca_checking").append(teks);`

So try this.

```
    $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "hanca/hanca_crud.php",
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
   id_hanca: id_hanca,
   type: "detail_hanca"
  }, //detail_hanca
  success: function(data) {

    var teks = "";
    $.each(data.detail, function(indeks, nilai) {
      //status hanca
      var tmp1 = nilai.status_detail_hanca;
      $("select.status_detail_hanca").val(tmp1);

      var no = nilai.no;
      var status_detail_hanca = "<select class='status_detail_hanca' name='status_detail_hanca[]' >\n\
        <option value='0'";
        if(tmp1 === '0') {
            status_detail_hanca += " selected ";
        }
      status_detail_hanca += ">Proses</option>\n\
        <option value='1'";
        if(tmp1 === '1') {
            status_detail_hanca += " selected ";
        }
      status_detail_hanca += ">Return</option>\n\
        <option value='2'";
        if(tmp1 === '2') {
            status_detail_hanca += " selected ";
        }                
      status_detail_hanca += ">Selesai</option>\n\
        </select>";
      teks += "<tr>" + no +
        "</td><td>" + status_detail_hanca +
        "</td></tr>";
    });
    $(".tbody_detail_hanca_checking").append(teks);
  }
});
```